# Is it possible for a .swf file to redirect to website?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a website where people upload swf files. What kinds of harm can be done from allowing this? Is it possible for a swf to redirect to another website? (It looks like someone may have done this already.) What can be done to prevent this aside from "processing" every entry manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head things you need to think about when letting anyone upload a swf to your site:

- If the SWF can execute JS on your website, all kinds of crazy things could happen. Be sure that you set the [allowScriptAccess param to never where you are embedding the SWF.](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/control-access-scripts-host-web.html)
- You may also want to [disable the SWF from going into full screen](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7c5d.html) to prevent phishing type scams
- You can even [disable networking all together from the SWF](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS1EFE2EDA-026D-4d14-864E-79DFD56F87C6.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7c5b). However, this would cripple a fair amount of legitimate content.
- Watch out for [CSRF-like attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) and make sure your site takes the appropriate security measures.

You can review [Adobe's article on FP security](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/secure_swf_apps.html) for a look at some more issues as well.